# Riemann tensor Contracted with full antisymmetric tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, symmetry, tensor-calculus, curvature

I'm not able to show that

$\epsilon^{abcd} R_{bcae} = 0$

Note: Properly, I have to show that
$\epsilon^{Iabc} R_{abIL} = 0$,
where $I,L$ are tetrad index and $a,b,c$ are spacetime index, but it should be the same as if you'll consider all of them as spacetime index.

Some hint?

Comment: Hint: First Bianchi identity.

Comment: It should be $R_{bcad}$ and not $R_{bcae}$.